# Analytics tracking Not working Properly

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, cloudflare

The Google analytics is not working properly after installing the cloudflare. I'm not sure what the problem is But the GA is Tracking Partially that is if get 50 visitors only 25 visitors are tracked other are not tracking for other site its working perfectly. Please help

Comment: Can you share the site?

Answer (score 0):

You might have issues if you're using two GA codes on the site (CloudFlare's app & then also Google's default way of doing it). This is really not something that can be looked at here & I would encourage you to open a support ticket.